# Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I am having an error regarding (Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.) any recommendations.

thanks

```
import keras
#For building the Neural Network layer by layer
from keras.models import Sequential
#To randomly initialize the weights to small numbers close to 0(But not 0)
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier=tf.keras.Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))




RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should only have to change the imports at the top:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
```

Comment: I have for pointing this out. I have done exactly what you listed up. but I have got the following error TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units' Thanks

Comment: This is an error in the Dense layer construction, different from the import error you had so far (so the code you have supplied above). In short, all layers have a required units parameter that defines the number of neurons. You can see more details in the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/)

Comment: do you mean units=6 as the input layer classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))

Comment: More like `classifier.add(Dense(6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (11,)))`. Input shape needs to be a tuple as per the documentation. This is kind of separate problem, so you might have to open a new question or check for existing examples of MLP implementations using keras.

Answer (score 5):

TensorFlow 2.0+ is only compatible with Keras 2.3.0+, so if you wish to use Keras 2.2.5-, you'll need TensorFlow 1.15.0-. Alternatively, yes, you can do `from tensorflow.keras import ...`, but that will not use your `keras` package at all and you might as well uninstall it.

Comment: There is a big difference between "can" and is actually supported, only Keras 2.3.x supports TensorFlow 2.0, so do not recommend to use 2.2.5 with it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Good thing there's a second half to that sentence

Comment: Yes, that's why I recommend not to mention partially supported TF versions.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro If anything, it _explicitly discourages_ using K2.2.5+TF2 - else the user may run it w/o error and think it's fine. But alright, guess I can make it more explicit - answer updated

Comment: No, now I found evidence that Keras 2.2.5 does not actually support TF 2.0, just look at [this commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/aa28910799bcd169d28ae1e5b50508c868df7380#diff-a18b8c6a1191d6f49303e0d599ca8c37R69), so just saying "can" is actually wrong.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Hmm... I'm possibly recalling something incorrectly - my mistake, thanks for pointing it out; fixed

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use `tensorflow 2.0+` you must have `keras 2.3+`
try to upgrade your keras it works for me :

```
pip install -U keras
```

or you may specify the keras version to 2.3

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Downgraded my TensorFlow to version 1.14 using the following:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

Fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

first, import tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Next, in place of this,

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
```

use:

```
classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code on the first cell worked for me

%tensorflow_version 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by running

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade keras
```