# ValueError: Arguments and signature arguments do not match. got: 13, expected: 14

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, uncertainty

I am trying to generate confidence intervals my keras model's predictions following the logic outlined in here: [How to calculate prediction uncertainty using Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529931/how-to-calculate-prediction-uncertainty-using-keras), and here: https://medium.com/hal24k-techblog/how-to-generate-neural-network-confidence-intervals-with-keras-e4c0b78ebbdf

I have searched on the Keras github issues page for similar issues which suggested I was using the wrong method to instantiate a new model with a predefined config, however despite changing my code from `Model.from_config()` to `tf.keras.Sequential.from_config()` the issue still persists.

Code as per below:

```
# Model
def mlp_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([   
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, input_dim = 3,
                          kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',
                          activation = 'elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu', 
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)),                     
    tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.3),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.003)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.003)),                                               
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'relu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.004)), #128 for unscaled
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer = opt, 
                loss = root_mean_squared_error,
                metrics=['mean_squared_error', 
                         'mean_absolute_error',
                         root_mean_squared_error])
  return model

# fit model
model = mlp_model()
model_history = model.fit(train_batch, 
                          validation_data = test_batch,
                          epochs = 100,
                          shuffle = False,
                          callbacks = [early_stop, 
                                       model_checkpoint,
                                       tensorboard_callback])

# Create dropout func 
def create_dropout_predict_function(model, dropout):

    # Load the config of the original model
    conf = model.get_config()

    # Add the specified dropout to all layers
    for layer in conf['layers']:
        # Dropout layers
        if layer["class_name"]=="Dropout":
            layer["config"]["rate"] = dropout

    # Using Functional API
    model_dropout = tf.keras.Sequential.from_config(conf)
    model_dropout.set_weights(model.get_weights()) 

    # Predict with dropout
    predict_with_dropout = K.function(model_dropout.inputs+[K.learning_phase()], model_dropout.outputs)

    return predict_with_dropout

# Create preds with dropout
dropout = 0.5
num_iter = 20
num_samples = len(forecast_ahead_df)

predict_with_dropout = create_dropout_predict_function(model, dropout)

predictions = np.zeros((num_samples, num_iter))

for i in range(num_iter):
    predictions[:, i] = predict_with_dropout(forecast_batch)
```

Any help much appreciated, and a big thank you to all that have helped so far.

Comment: Version errors should be addressed before anything else - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090404/keras-that-does-not-support-tensorflow-2-0-we-recommend-using-tf-keras-or-al/59090586#59090586)

Comment: I am currently using TensorFlow 2.0 here, but good point. Is the most recent Keras update not included in this?

Comment: Keras 2.3.0 and Keras 2.3.1 support TF2, yes, but not any earlier versions (2.2.5, etc)

Comment: Ive now upgraded to 2.3.0 and I am receiving a different error: '
'UnimplementedError: Cast variant to float is not supported [Op:Cast] name: Cast/'

Comment: Changing versions in conda is tricky - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944060/anaconda-installs-tensorflow-1-15-instead-of-2-0/58944276#58944276); make sure `keras` is fully uninstalled before installing ver. 2.3.0+

Comment: I actually ended up getting into a mess here and ended up reinstalling a lot of things but I am back to TF 2.0 and keras 2.3.0, but sadly still the same error :(

Comment: Where in your code is the attribute error being produced?

Comment: This is rather strange -- include the following info: your operating system, CUDA & cuDNN versions, full error trace. Also are you using an Anaconda virtual environment? If not, here's a tip that'll go a long way: delete your Anaconda entirely, reinstall it without any additional packages, then _create a new virtual environment_ by cloning base (`conda create --name new_env --clone base`) - and install everything to that virtual env. If something breaks, very easy to start over w/o reinstalling everything. For example, I have `tf1_env` and `tf2_env`, and switching between is trivial.

Comment: deleting previous comments as I have solved the version issue and data input issue. I have simply turned the forecast df into an numpy array. The error now is: `ValueError: Arguments and signature arguments do not match. got: 13, expected: 14`. Apologies for the lengthy responses here.

Comment: Hi @OverLordGoldDragon just wondering whether you might have an idea of what is causing the issue now I have fixed the version problems? many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on tensorflow version 2.0.0 and no GPU, but hopefully this still fixes the problems. It seems like you are only feeding your network input data (X), but no respond data (Y). So there is nothing for the model to learn. I only added the response data Y in `model.fit()`.

I have used your code and trained on the [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv) dataset. The following code worked for me in tensorflow 2.0.0, see comment for changes:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
import numpy as np

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("/content/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# Changed the Input Dimenseion to input_dim = 8
def mlp_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([   
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, input_dim = 8,
                          kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',
                          activation = 'elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu', 
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)),                     
    tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.3),  
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.003)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'elu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.003)),                                               
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(160, 
                          activation = 'relu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.004)), #128 for unscaled
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
  ])

  # Removed unavailable functions and used the tensorflow available optimizer, loss and metrics
  model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['mean_squared_error', 
                         'mean_absolute_error'])
  return model

# fit model
model = mlp_model()
# Added the response variable Y
model_history = model.fit(X, Y,
                          epochs = 100)
```

Output -

```
2.0.0
Train on 768 samples
Epoch 1/100
768/768 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 8.1430 - mean_squared_error: 105.6280 - mean_absolute_error: 8.0280
Epoch 2/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 11.3845 - mean_squared_error: 819.4331 - mean_absolute_error: 25.4116
Epoch 3/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 96us/sample - loss: 11.2765 - mean_squared_error: 1185.4595 - mean_absolute_error: 30.9923
Epoch 4/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 11.1805 - mean_squared_error: 1230.1932 - mean_absolute_error: 31.5183
Epoch 5/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 11.0962 - mean_squared_error: 1161.8567 - mean_absolute_error: 30.6245
Epoch 6/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 11.0217 - mean_squared_error: 1129.4146 - mean_absolute_error: 30.2203
Epoch 7/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 10.9550 - mean_squared_error: 1097.7333 - mean_absolute_error: 29.7042
Epoch 8/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 10.8947 - mean_squared_error: 1066.2788 - mean_absolute_error: 29.1740
Epoch 9/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.8396 - mean_squared_error: 1035.1652 - mean_absolute_error: 28.6741
Epoch 10/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.7892 - mean_squared_error: 987.1348 - mean_absolute_error: 28.0417
Epoch 11/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.7427 - mean_squared_error: 947.6363 - mean_absolute_error: 27.4314
Epoch 12/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.6997 - mean_squared_error: 891.5195 - mean_absolute_error: 26.5769
Epoch 13/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.6599 - mean_squared_error: 868.7969 - mean_absolute_error: 26.1633
Epoch 14/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 94us/sample - loss: 10.6230 - mean_squared_error: 818.0642 - mean_absolute_error: 25.2891
Epoch 15/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.5886 - mean_squared_error: 772.1309 - mean_absolute_error: 24.7540
Epoch 16/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 10.5567 - mean_squared_error: 745.1671 - mean_absolute_error: 24.1730
Epoch 17/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.5269 - mean_squared_error: 691.4273 - mean_absolute_error: 23.3115
Epoch 18/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 109us/sample - loss: 10.4991 - mean_squared_error: 651.1308 - mean_absolute_error: 22.6068
Epoch 19/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 10.4732 - mean_squared_error: 634.8137 - mean_absolute_error: 22.2203
Epoch 20/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.4489 - mean_squared_error: 600.7214 - mean_absolute_error: 21.5552
Epoch 21/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 10.4262 - mean_squared_error: 557.6275 - mean_absolute_error: 20.9041
Epoch 22/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.4050 - mean_squared_error: 533.1421 - mean_absolute_error: 20.3297
Epoch 23/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.3850 - mean_squared_error: 528.4443 - mean_absolute_error: 19.9225
Epoch 24/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 10.3663 - mean_squared_error: 488.9399 - mean_absolute_error: 19.3189
Epoch 25/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.3487 - mean_squared_error: 448.7306 - mean_absolute_error: 18.5765
Epoch 26/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 10.3322 - mean_squared_error: 425.1384 - mean_absolute_error: 18.0467
Epoch 27/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.3166 - mean_squared_error: 390.8499 - mean_absolute_error: 17.3933
Epoch 28/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 10.3019 - mean_squared_error: 373.9980 - mean_absolute_error: 16.8805
Epoch 29/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.2881 - mean_squared_error: 358.0975 - mean_absolute_error: 16.4838
Epoch 30/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.2750 - mean_squared_error: 330.0729 - mean_absolute_error: 15.8146
Epoch 31/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 94us/sample - loss: 10.2627 - mean_squared_error: 304.5206 - mean_absolute_error: 15.1873
Epoch 32/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 96us/sample - loss: 10.2510 - mean_squared_error: 284.8553 - mean_absolute_error: 14.7007
Epoch 33/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.2400 - mean_squared_error: 269.9680 - mean_absolute_error: 14.2868
Epoch 34/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.2295 - mean_squared_error: 258.1902 - mean_absolute_error: 13.8228
Epoch 35/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.2196 - mean_squared_error: 233.8299 - mean_absolute_error: 13.2536
Epoch 36/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.2102 - mean_squared_error: 226.0575 - mean_absolute_error: 12.8807
Epoch 37/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.2013 - mean_squared_error: 208.6756 - mean_absolute_error: 12.4301
Epoch 38/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.1928 - mean_squared_error: 190.1977 - mean_absolute_error: 11.8795
Epoch 39/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.1847 - mean_squared_error: 179.3409 - mean_absolute_error: 11.5069
Epoch 40/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.1770 - mean_squared_error: 164.0748 - mean_absolute_error: 11.0245
Epoch 41/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.1697 - mean_squared_error: 154.7774 - mean_absolute_error: 10.5896
Epoch 42/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.1627 - mean_squared_error: 138.8940 - mean_absolute_error: 10.1659
Epoch 43/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.1560 - mean_squared_error: 130.8000 - mean_absolute_error: 9.8535
Epoch 44/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.1496 - mean_squared_error: 120.8661 - mean_absolute_error: 9.4153
Epoch 45/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 10.1435 - mean_squared_error: 109.2852 - mean_absolute_error: 9.0433
Epoch 46/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.1377 - mean_squared_error: 103.8257 - mean_absolute_error: 8.6843
Epoch 47/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 93us/sample - loss: 10.1322 - mean_squared_error: 96.0696 - mean_absolute_error: 8.3516
Epoch 48/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 95us/sample - loss: 10.1268 - mean_squared_error: 87.2735 - mean_absolute_error: 7.9551
Epoch 49/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 10.1217 - mean_squared_error: 78.5033 - mean_absolute_error: 7.5730
Epoch 50/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.1168 - mean_squared_error: 73.8310 - mean_absolute_error: 7.2905
Epoch 51/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 96us/sample - loss: 10.1121 - mean_squared_error: 65.5390 - mean_absolute_error: 6.9333
Epoch 52/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 94us/sample - loss: 10.1076 - mean_squared_error: 62.0906 - mean_absolute_error: 6.6996
Epoch 53/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 93us/sample - loss: 10.1033 - mean_squared_error: 54.6800 - mean_absolute_error: 6.3188
Epoch 54/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.0991 - mean_squared_error: 49.5616 - mean_absolute_error: 6.0299
Epoch 55/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 10.0951 - mean_squared_error: 46.1167 - mean_absolute_error: 5.7707
Epoch 56/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.0913 - mean_squared_error: 41.3520 - mean_absolute_error: 5.4638
Epoch 57/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 98us/sample - loss: 10.0876 - mean_squared_error: 37.7623 - mean_absolute_error: 5.2175
Epoch 58/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.0840 - mean_squared_error: 35.0457 - mean_absolute_error: 4.9933
Epoch 59/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.0806 - mean_squared_error: 31.3319 - mean_absolute_error: 4.6894
Epoch 60/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.0773 - mean_squared_error: 28.8361 - mean_absolute_error: 4.5389
Epoch 61/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 92us/sample - loss: 10.0741 - mean_squared_error: 25.4872 - mean_absolute_error: 4.2417
Epoch 62/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0710 - mean_squared_error: 23.8177 - mean_absolute_error: 4.1007
Epoch 63/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 7.0914 - mean_squared_error: 101.6586 - mean_absolute_error: 7.4064
Epoch 64/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 5.5155 - mean_squared_error: 457.9014 - mean_absolute_error: 18.0251
Epoch 65/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 5.5088 - mean_squared_error: 392.7791 - mean_absolute_error: 16.7004
Epoch 66/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 98us/sample - loss: 5.5000 - mean_squared_error: 272.5681 - mean_absolute_error: 13.7357
Epoch 67/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 5.4928 - mean_squared_error: 188.3301 - mean_absolute_error: 11.4254
Epoch 68/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 5.4869 - mean_squared_error: 144.7060 - mean_absolute_error: 10.0285
Epoch 69/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 5.4821 - mean_squared_error: 160.2795 - mean_absolute_error: 10.7119
Epoch 70/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 94us/sample - loss: 5.4772 - mean_squared_error: 114.1624 - mean_absolute_error: 9.0611
Epoch 71/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 5.4729 - mean_squared_error: 81.6616 - mean_absolute_error: 7.5558
Epoch 72/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 5.4690 - mean_squared_error: 58.3508 - mean_absolute_error: 6.3955
Epoch 73/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 5.4654 - mean_squared_error: 44.2179 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5208
Epoch 74/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 5.4621 - mean_squared_error: 33.7123 - mean_absolute_error: 4.7988
Epoch 75/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 97us/sample - loss: 5.4590 - mean_squared_error: 26.4150 - mean_absolute_error: 4.2291
Epoch 76/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 5.4561 - mean_squared_error: 21.0693 - mean_absolute_error: 3.7517
Epoch 77/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 82us/sample - loss: 5.4533 - mean_squared_error: 16.6050 - mean_absolute_error: 3.3334
Epoch 78/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 5.4507 - mean_squared_error: 13.3761 - mean_absolute_error: 2.9838
Epoch 79/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 94us/sample - loss: 5.4482 - mean_squared_error: 10.6811 - mean_absolute_error: 2.6628
Epoch 80/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 5.4459 - mean_squared_error: 9.5541 - mean_absolute_error: 2.4669
Epoch 81/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 5.4438 - mean_squared_error: 11.0352 - mean_absolute_error: 2.7847
Epoch 82/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 5.4416 - mean_squared_error: 8.8724 - mean_absolute_error: 2.4634
Epoch 83/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 96us/sample - loss: 5.4395 - mean_squared_error: 7.0467 - mean_absolute_error: 2.1836
Epoch 84/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 8.0375 - mean_squared_error: 36.5165 - mean_absolute_error: 4.8413
Epoch 85/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0764 - mean_squared_error: 126.9524 - mean_absolute_error: 10.2454
Epoch 86/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 87us/sample - loss: 10.0705 - mean_squared_error: 121.3718 - mean_absolute_error: 9.9911
Epoch 87/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.0631 - mean_squared_error: 96.0288 - mean_absolute_error: 8.9118
Epoch 88/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0572 - mean_squared_error: 74.3836 - mean_absolute_error: 7.9054
Epoch 89/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.0524 - mean_squared_error: 62.7223 - mean_absolute_error: 7.1927
Epoch 90/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 90us/sample - loss: 10.0484 - mean_squared_error: 48.8116 - mean_absolute_error: 6.4094
Epoch 91/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 93us/sample - loss: 10.0448 - mean_squared_error: 39.1147 - mean_absolute_error: 5.7639
Epoch 92/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0417 - mean_squared_error: 32.7087 - mean_absolute_error: 5.2643
Epoch 93/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 85us/sample - loss: 10.0389 - mean_squared_error: 26.4908 - mean_absolute_error: 4.7354
Epoch 94/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0363 - mean_squared_error: 21.6876 - mean_absolute_error: 4.2937
Epoch 95/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 89us/sample - loss: 10.0340 - mean_squared_error: 17.6745 - mean_absolute_error: 3.8886
Epoch 96/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 86us/sample - loss: 10.0318 - mean_squared_error: 14.5234 - mean_absolute_error: 3.5385
Epoch 97/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 93us/sample - loss: 10.0298 - mean_squared_error: 12.3609 - mean_absolute_error: 3.2538
Epoch 98/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 91us/sample - loss: 10.0279 - mean_squared_error: 10.0023 - mean_absolute_error: 2.9435
Epoch 99/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.0261 - mean_squared_error: 8.6058 - mean_absolute_error: 2.7176
Epoch 100/100
768/768 [==============================] - 0s 88us/sample - loss: 10.0244 - mean_squared_error: 7.0987 - mean_absolute_error: 2.4628
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I should perhaps have mentioned that I am generating examples using tf.data.DataSet. Here, train_batch is X, y tuple. I believe the error has been fixed in any case in tensorflow 2.0 - it perhaps lay in the use of the DataSet generator.

Comment: Glad to know its fixed. So you mean the issue persisted in lower tensorflow version but worked fine in tensorflow 2.0. Can you please let us know the tensorflow version you faced the error. May be we can rewrite the answer for benefit of the community.