# how to solve ''looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0''

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow 2 version for running a sequentional model. I am not sure why it does not support tensorflow2. I also checked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090404/keras-that-does-not-support-tensorflow-2-0-we-recommend-using-tf-keras-or-al), but it doesn't help. can anyone help me to correct the code?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow
import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(32,32,4),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1024,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=1024,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="linear"))

#compile model
optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae'])
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/appl/soft/ai/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow-2.0.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 66, in _get_default_graph
    return tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError: It looks like you are trying to use a version of multi-backend Keras that does not support TensorFlow 2.0. We recommend using `tf.keras`, or alternatively, downgrading to TensorFlow 1.14.
```

Comment: What is your keras version

Comment: Maybe instead of flipping a coin to decide whether you are going to import from `keras` or `tf.keras`, try to be consistent here... The error message even tells you to use `tf.keras`.

Comment: keras version is '2.2.5'

Comment: You are mixing imports between keras and tf.keras and that is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run the code by editing the section for importing the libraries:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers                                                                                                                                                             from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: be aware, future tf release may remove `tensorflow.python.keras`  to only `tensorflow.keras`.